# How to remotely add a line under of specific line in Python

Tags: python

I have this .py file:

```
some imports

#TypeA
var_1 = ("some code...")
var_2 = ("some code...")
...
#TypeB
var_3 = ("some code...")
var_4 = ("some code...")
```

I would like to add a new line under #TypeA and another line under #TypeB etc.
What I have now is:

```
with open('file.py', 'r+') as file:
file_content = file.readlines()

file_content.insert(1,'var_0 = ("some code...")\n')
```

but here I have to declare the specific line.

Comment: How will you add a line of code somewhere **without** specifying what line you want it on?

Comment: You may find the index of TypeA and TypeB it'd be easier

Comment: Do you want to insert the line into the actual file, or just the in-memory list of its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps may be

- read the file
- find `Type A` and insert the new line
- find `Type B` and insert the new line
- reset file cursor at the beginning (to avoid appending)
- write the lines

```
with open('file.py', 'r+') as file:
    file_content = file.readlines()
    idx_A = file_content.index("# TypeA\n")
    file_content.insert(idx_A+1, 'var_0 = ("some code...")\n')

    idx_B = file_content.index("# TypeB\n")
    file_content.insert(idx_B+1, 'var_00 = ("some code...")\n')

    file.seek(0)
    file.writelines(file_content)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search for #TypeA with a for loop.

```
i = 0
for line in file_content:
    if line.strip() == "#TypeA":
        file_content.insert(i+1, "var_0 = ('some code...')\n")
        break
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about looping through filecontent to find the index for TypeA adn TypeB?

```
TypeAIndex = 0
for i in file_content:
    if "# TypeA" in i:
        TypeAIndex = i
        break
```

This example could do with some polish but it should give you the idea.